# UNC path is Replaced by Mapped Drive

Tags: c#, ms-access, mapped-drive

I am attempting to get data from an Access database and send it to an identical table in a SQL database.

```
using (OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(sourceConnectionString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT * FROM {sourceTableName}", oleDbConnection))
    {
        oleDbConnection.Open();

        using (OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnectionString))
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The sourceConnectionString contains a data source equal to a UNC path (e.g.  \\server\fileshare\folder\accessDB.accdb).  When I step through the code and get to `oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()`, an exception is thrown saying

> Y:\folder\accessDB.accdb is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

I have no idea why the UNC path (\\server\fileshare) was replaced with a mapped drive (Y:\).
There is nothing in my code to set or use a mapped drive.  All properties in `oleDbconnection` and `oleDbCommand` reference the UNC path.

If I create a mapped drive to the UNC path.  The `oleDbCommnand.ExecuteReader()` will work and no exceptions are thrown.

I'd appreciate any ideas why the UNC path is defaulting to a mapped drive.  I assume it is a default on the server or my PC that the network team set up. I have no clue how to verify it.  For now, I'll have to ensure the end user's PC has a Y: drive mapped to the fileshare on the server.

Comment: are you doing this as a one time operation?

Comment: No, this will be a routine process.

Comment: As an alternative approach, you might be able to do away with the oledbconn and sqlbulkcopy entirely if you form some C# that tells your SQLServer to connect to the Access db : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 - you could then fill your table with an INSERT/SELECT or SELECT/INTO

Comment: ...Or, alternatively, ODBC-map the SQL-Server table into Access, and create an INSERT...SELECT query in ACCESS and automate the running of the Access DB instead of the C#.